# Tensorflow tensor T1 of shape b*n*3. T2 of shape b*n -> A boolean tensor indicating which rows to take in T1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to extract specific rows among `n` points 3D coordinates and `b` batches.  Essentially my tensor `T1` is of shape `b*n*3`. I have another boolean tensor `T2` of shape `b * n` indicating which rows of `n` needs to be taking.
Essentially my output should be `b*?*3` since `T2` can have varied number of 1s in each batch.

I have implemented the following using boolean mask but the output is not as expected and output shape is `(?,)` but not `(b*?*3)`.

```
# expand T2 to (b,n,3). i.e. 0 replicates to (0,0,0) and so is 1

mask = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(T2,2), [1,1,3])

# query using boolean mask where there are 1s

valid_KPs = tf.boolean_mask(T1, tf.cast(mask, tf.int32))
```

Comment: If `T2` can have a different number of 1s in each example, then the result cannot be a proper tensor, as the size of the second dimension would be different in each case. That would be something like a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors), but that is not very supported. With regular tensors, the best you could aim for is a tensor where examples would need to be "padded" so all have the same size (and another tensor indicating the number of valid entries for each example).

Comment: Thanks jdehesa. Could you provide example with ragged tensor only?

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of selected elements for each example may be different, that cannot be expressed as a proper tensor. One option could be using a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors). They cannot do everything that a normal tensor can, but it is possible to achieve what you want for example like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Input data
    t1 = tf.constant([
        [
            [ 1,  2,  3],
            [ 4,  5,  6],
            [ 7,  8,  9],
        ],
        [
            [10, 11, 12],
            [13, 14, 15],
            [16, 17, 18],
        ],
    ])
    t2 = tf.constant([
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
    ])
    # Count the number of ones for each row in T2
    c = tf.reduce_sum(t2, axis=1)
    # Ragged ranges for each row
    r = tf.ragged.range(c)
    # Sorting indices so indices with a one are first
    s = tf.argsort(t2, axis=1, direction='DESCENDING', stable=True)
    # First axis dimension index
    idx0 = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(t1)[0]), 1) * tf.ones_like(r)
    # 2D index for getting indices of ones on each row
    idx_s = tf.stack([idx0, r], axis=-1)
    # Get indices of ones
    idx1 = tf.gather_nd(s, idx_s)
    # 2D index to get indices of selected vectors in T1
    idx = tf.stack([idx0, idx1], axis=-1)
    # Get selected vectors
    result = tf.gather_nd(t1, idx)
    # Print result
    print(sess.run(result))
    # <tf.RaggedTensorValue [[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], [[13, 14, 15]]]>
```